# require php code for sending push notification on android devices using ACS

Tags: php, android, appcelerator-mobile

I want to send the push notifications on android devices using php,
I am using ACS( Appcelerator cloud Services ) for that.
here is my code, if anyone found any solution then please share it.

```
$tmp_fname = "cookie.txt";
$curl_handle = curl_init('https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/users   /login.json?key=uGDhfoFYdIwwyCKQMzKlSuNIPxl3CBSd');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmp_fname);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmp_fname);
$post_array = array('login' => 'abs', 'password' => '123456');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);
$output = curl_exec($curl_handle);
//$session = json_decode($output);
print_r($output);
$json = '{"badge": 1,"sound": "default","alert" : "Abdul Sattar Testing"}';
$Curl_Session2 = curl_init('https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/push_notification/notify.json?key=uGDhfoFYdIwwyCKQMzKlSuNIPxl3CBSd&to_ids=ND1TQ9BM8TW4GYASMP2MJ84');
curl_setopt($Curl_Session2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "$tmp_fname");
curl_setopt($Curl_Session2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "$tmp_fname");
curl_setopt($Curl_Session2, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($Curl_Session2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($Curl_Session2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "channel=friend_request&payload=" . $json);
curl_setopt($Curl_Session2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$res2 = curl_exec($Curl_Session2);
$response = curl_getinfo($Curl_Session2);
print_r($res2);
echo '<br /><br />';
print_r($response);
curl_close($Curl_Session2);
```

Comment: I have also tried once to do push notification using Appacelerator. But unfortunately I have to use Local Notifications!

Comment: local notifications means "In App" or "Active App" notifications?

Comment: can you please share your code for more help?

Answer (score 0):

Already tried this?
https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/
It's Cloud to Device Messaging. It makes it easier to create push notifiactions.

Hope could helpya
:)

edit:
maybe this can help you too.
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/137264/php-curl-problem-acs-push-notification